# How to pass tablename ,columnname and value into Storedprocedure in Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying this one ,but it throws error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE usp_dynamicExc1 (Tablename varchar(100)
,Columnname  varchar(100),
Data varchar(100) )
BEGIN
SET @Tablename = Tablename;
SET @columnname = Columnname;
SET @value1 = Data;
SET @q= CONCAT('Insert into ',@tablename,' (',@columnname,') values (',@value1,')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt ;    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

**I got this error**

```
10:30:16    PREPARE stmt FROM @q    Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1    0.000 sec
```

Comment: Just create parameters in Procedure for table name and pass it at time of calling. Let me know if not clear to you.

Comment: It's easy to debug this - just add a select '@'q before the prepare and comment out the prepare,execute and deallocate. BTW you are missing a ; after set @value = data (which I assume is a transcription error),the end statement should be followed by the delimiter, '@''query_table and  '@'newrecord are not  allocated values so will be null which will result in the concat returning null and you are missing a values clause in your insert statement,

Comment: Can you tell me clearly?

Comment: Not any more clearly.

Comment: I Tried but still data was not inserted

Comment: with this call p('users','id,username','999,bob'); your insert statement look like this INSERT INTO `users(id,username)`( 
`999,bob`)  - does that look right to you? note the spaces are misinterpreted back ticks on this site.